# Oracle left join throws an error, but inner join works

Tags: oracle, join

I have a query that consists of a join between two tables.  When it is an inner join, the query works fine.  However, when I change it to an outer join, it throws an error as if the secondary table was not defined in the query.

Here is what I mean:

```
select a.unit
     , a.data_date
from ( 
        select unit
             , person
             , data_date
        from the_data
     ) a
     join personnel b
     on (
          b.person = a.person
          and b.first_date <= a.data_date
          and b.last_date >= a.data_date
        )
```

the_data and personnel are tables

This works as written, but if you change the join to a left join, it reports that a.data_date is an invalid identifier (and if you rewrite the ON clause so the top line is at the bottom, it will say that a.person is invalid).

I vaguely remember coming across this once before, and it turned out to be an internal Oracle bug.

The database is 64-bit version 11.2.0.4.0.

Comment: Please show the COMPLETE error message.

Comment: Error at line 14

ORA-00904: "A"."DATA_DATE": invalid identifier

Comment: What is the reason for subquery `from ( 
        select unit
             , person
             , data_date
        from the_data
     ) a` ?

Comment: What is your question? You already know it’s a bug, so are you askng for confirmation of that, or a workaround, or something else? And do you still see the issue without the unnecessary subquery against the first table?

Comment: It's rewritten from a larger query; I left the subquery in.  Note that when I remove the subquery (i.e. make it "from the_data a left join personnel b"), the same problem happens.

Something else; it works on another Oracle database that is also 11.2.0.4.0.

Comment: Alex - yes, I am trying to see if there is a workaround, or, failing that, if anyone has had a similar problem and knew, for example, what patches fixed it.  Is there a way for a non-DBA to find out what patches have been applied to a particular database?

Comment: @DonDelGrande - Yes, if you are a non-DBA, you can find out what patches have been applied by asking the DBA.